# Is it possible to represent the following fraction in a series form

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

I need to represent the following fraction in a series form $$\frac{ax}{(a+b)x+2a\sqrt{x}+a}$$ where $a>0,b>0$.

Comment: at which point for $x$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner isn't there a general series that represent the above fraction for all values of $x$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I have founf the series at $x=\infty$ from wolfram alpha

Comment: yes i can try $x=m$ for example

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner actually I have this fraction multiplies by an exponential function and I have to integrate the product. Now, if I can represent the above fraction as a general series form then I can solve the integral

Comment: Let $x=y^2$ and expand around whatever you want.